# (jQuery) Problem accessing custom properties with extend()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've assigned a custom property called name to a jquery div element. I'm able to access that property manually with div1.name, but I'm not able to access it through a mouse event by using $(this).

```
  var div1 = $('<div></div>');
  div1.css("width", "100px");
  div1.css("height", "100px");
  div1.css("background-color", "red");
  div1.mouseover(sayName);
  $('body').append(div1);

  var div2 = $('<div></div>');
  div2.css("width", "100px");
  div2.css("height", "100px");
  div2.css("background-color", "green");
  div2.mouseover(sayName);
  $('body').append(div2);

  div1.extend({"name":"Red"});
  div2.extend({"name":"Green"});

  function sayName() {
    console.log(div1.name); // prints Red
    console.log(div2.name); // prints Green
    console.log($(this).name); // prints undefined
  }
```

I need a way to access name by using $(this)

Comment: I am pretty sure you are referencing another object when you are referencing to `$(this)`. At that point you are in the scope of `sayName()` function.

Comment: I guess you can't because when you appended the divs to the DOM they didn't had the name attribute, so when you catch them on the event there is no attribute name attached to them.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do isn't possible, as you set the `name` property to a specific `jQuery` instance, whereas a new instance is created each time you call `$(this)`, although it contains the same HTML element.

What you can do, instead, is use a getter/setter combo to get/set a `data-*` attribute:

```js
/* Expand jQuery.fn to have the 'name' property. */
Object.defineProperty($.fn, "name", {
  get: function () {
    /* Return the value of the first element's 'data-name' attribute. */
    return this[0].dataset.name;
  },
  set: function (value) {
    /* Iterate over every element in the context. */
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
      /* Set the value as the value of the element's 'data-name' attribute. */
      this[i].dataset.name = value;
    };
  }
});

$(function () {
  /* Set the 'name' property of the element (sets 'data-name'). */
  $("#element").name = "Fancy Div";
  
  /* Get the value of the 'name' property (gets 'data-name'). */
  console.log($("#element").name);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "element"></div>
```

---

Since, usually, you're more likely to want to add multiple properties this way, here's a quick plugin that encapsulates this functionality:

```js
/* Create a method that can set properties as described. */
$.fn.set = function (property, value) {
  /* Create the object that will contain the given property/ies. */
  var obj = (typeof property == "object") ? {...property || {}} : {[property]: value};
  
  /* Iterate over every property in the given object. */
  for (let property in obj) {
    /* Check whether the property doesn't already exist. */
    if (!(property in $.fn)) {
      /* Expand jQuery.fn to have the 'name' property. */
      Object.defineProperty($.fn, property, {
        get: function () {
          /* Return the value of the first element's data-* attribute. */
          return this[0].dataset[property];
        },
        set: function (value) {
          /* Set the value of every element's data-* attribute. */
          this.each(index => this[index].dataset[property] = value);
        }
      });
    }

    /* Update the property with the new value. */
    this[property] = obj[property];
  }
  
  /* Return the context. */
  return this;
};


$(function () {
  /* Set some properties of the element. */
  $("#element")
    .set("name", "Fancy Div")
    .set({type: "container", value: 0});
  
  /* Get some properties of the element. */
  console.log("name: " + $("#element").name);
  console.log("type: " + $("#element").type);
  console.log("value: " + $("#element").value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "element"></div>
```